# Python list comprehension instead of for loop using regular expression

Tags: python

New to python, I have the following code which works in returning a new list of only relevant txt files using re:

```
import re

txtList = ['file123.txt', 'file124.txt', 'file1dZ.txt']
newList = []

txtPattern = re.compile('file\d\d\d.txt')

for file in txtList:
    if txtPattern.match(file):
        newList.append(file)

print(newList)
```

I now want to practice and use list comprehension in place of the for loop.  I am having trouble with getting the Match Objects match() method to cooperate on one line of code.  How would I do this, and can I use a lambda expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line you are looking for is:

```
newList = [file for file in txtList if txtPattern.match(file)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You asked for a list comprehension, but in this case I would prefer to use `filter`:

```
newList = list(filter(txtPattern.match, txtList))
```